# how to handle NSFileHandle writeData method exception?

Tags: ios, swift, file-handling, nsfilehandle

To log any message on file I am using `writeData` method of `NSFileHandle`. Sometimes this method throws an exception but I can not handle it because code is written in swift.

Is there any work around ?

I have tried this :

```
I have tried this : NS_INLINE NSException * _Nullable tryBlock(void(^_Nonnull tryBlock)(void)) {
@try {
    tryBlock();
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    return exception;
}
return nil;
```

Comment: Show,  what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you mention the Exception please